# Unexpectedly found nil but I can print the value

Tags: ios, json, swift, null

EDIT: Add some more relevant details.

So for my app, I want to have three pages that show different weather information. I can scroll horizontally to view them. I followed this youtube video and the Github project for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s
https://github.com/ibrdrahim/slidePage

What I did is add a scroll view in the main storyboard. Then I create three Cocoa Touch class with xib. Each of them is subclass of UIViewController. Each xib will act as a page in the scroll view.

This is the code I used for set up xib view.

```
let xOrigin = self.view.frame.width

let credit : CreditScreenView = CreditScreenView(nibName: "CreditScreenView", bundle: nil)

mainScroll.addSubview(credit.view)

let forcast : ForcastScreenView = ForcastScreenView(nibName: "ForcastScreenView", bundle: nil)

mainScroll.addSubview(forcast.view)

let now : NowScreenView = NowScreenView(nibName: "NowScreenView", bundle: nil)

mainScroll.addSubview(now.view)

// set up the size for each view
credit.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

forcast.view.frame = CGRect(x: xOrigin, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

now.view.frame = CGRect(x: xOrigin * 2, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

mainScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(view.frame.width * 3), height: CGFloat(view.frame.height))
mainScroll.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width * 3
```

[image]

This is all the connected outlet on the NowScreenView.

updateWeatherData is called after the app get JSON.

```
func  getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String : String]) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success! Got the weather data")

            let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            print(weatherJSON)

            self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)
        }
        else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            self.cityLabel.text = "链\n接\n不\n可\n用"
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am doing my first iOS app now. It's a weather app. I got a fatal error which I don't understand why. What I want to do is to assign the location data I got from a JSON file to the cityLabel on the screen. So it shows the city name. 
Right now I can print the value of the location data in JSON, but if I want to assign it to the label it will give me the fatal error.

```
func updateWeatherData(json : JSON) {
    let data = json["HeWeather6"][0]
    let status = data["status"].stringValue
    //print(json)
    if status == "ok" {
        let tmpsNow = data["now"]["tmp"].intValue

        weatherDataModel.temperature = tmpsNow
        weatherDataModel.city = data["basic"]["location"].stringValue
        weatherDataModel.condition = data["now"]["cond_code"].intValue            
        weatherDataModel.weatherIconName = weatherDataModel.updateWeatherIcon(condition: weatherDataModel.condition)

        updateUIWithWeatherData()
    } else {
        cityLabel.text = "天\n气\n不\n可\n用"
    }   
}
```

This is how I got data from the JSON. There is another weatherDataModel.swift to sort the JSON data.

```
func updateUIWithWeatherData() {
    cityLabel.text = "\(weatherDataModel.city)"
    nowTemp.text = "\(weatherDataModel.temperature)º"
    weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherDataModel.weatherIconName)!
}
```

This is how I update UI once I got the weather data.

I got the fatal error on this line

```
cityLabel.text = "\(weatherDataModel.city)"
```

[image]

I try to `print(weatherDataModel.city)`, it will print the city name with no error. But I just couldn't assign the value to cityLabel. Could someone help me figure out what is the problem? Thanks!

This is the GitHub link in case someone wants to take a look at the full code. https://github.com/lucky13820/air

Comment: Don't focus on just one variable on that line. There are other variables on that line. `cityLabel` is nil. Connect your outlets.

Comment: @rmaddy I did connect cityLabel as an IBOutlet. I also give it some value in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Use your debugger. Confirm which value is really `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, you are right. All my labels are nil. Including cityLabel, nowTemp, weatherIcon. Not sure what should do with this.

Comment: Update your question with some relevant details. Show the outlet declarations. Explain how this view controller is created and displayed. Show how and when your `updateWeatherData` method is called.

Comment: You need to keep strong references to the view controllers whose views you are adding to the scroll view.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I am still new to Swift.

Comment: @lucky13820 I just checked your code , i figured out why this crash is happening please have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compiled your code, Issue is not with your model, issue is with your **ViewController.swift** class, first of all you are creating view with nib file like this way.

```
NowScreenView(nibName: "NowScreenView", bundle: nil)
```

mistake you are doing this point is, creating class level variable like this way. that is totally wrong.

```
let nowWeather = NowScreenView()
```

**NowScreenView** is not shared class its simple view class by doing this you can not get reference of your NowScreenView and thats why you are getting nil label,true way to get reference of your **NowScreenView** is

```
nowWeather  = NowScreenView(nibName: "NowScreenView", bundle: nil)
```

Now **nowWeather** has reference of your view and you can access your view data member.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding .stringValue to the end of weatherDataModel.temperature = tmpsNow because it appears that you are trying to put an int value in a label. Let me know if this helps.